# CSS sticky header onscroll

Tags: javascript, css, drupal-8

I'm working with a Drupal 8.x template and I need to modify a sticky header that it get activated onscroll.

The header is transparent when the page load and ones the user scroll down it has a white background and it get stuck at the top of the page (just as a sticky header normally works...)

What I want to do it's to modify the code so it won't start transparent. I need it to have the white background from the start, as soon as the page loads and of course with the sticky function.

These are the two codes i found that make the sticky header work. Hope someone can help me!

**CSS**

```
.onscroll.transparent-header-active .header-container.js-transparent-header .sticky-wrapper {
  height: 0 !important;
}
.onscroll .header.js-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 499;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 14px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1), 0 2px 2px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 14px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1), 0 2px 2px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
}
.onscroll .header.js-fixed.region--white-background {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
}
.onscroll .header.js-fixed.region--black-background {
  background-color: rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.95);
}
.onscroll .header.js-fixed.region--gray-background {
  background-color: rgba(244, 244, 244, 0.95);
}
.fixed-header-enabled.onscroll .header__container,
.fixed-header-enabled.onscroll .header-second,
.fixed-header-enabled.onscroll .header-third,
.fixed-header-enabled.onscroll .header-first,
.fixed-header-enabled.onscroll .header-container ul.menu {
  -webkit-transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
  -o-transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
.fixed-header-enabled.onscroll .header__container {
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.fixed-header-enabled.onscroll .header__section ul.menu {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.fixed-header-enabled.onscroll .header__section .field--mt-dropdowns-block {
  padding-top: 14px;
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .onscroll .header__container > .row > div {
    display: none;
  }
  .onscroll .header__container > .row > div:last-of-type {
    display: block;
  }
  .onscroll .header-container .content > ul.menu {
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .onscroll .header.js-fixed {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.mtWaypointsFixedHeader = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $(context).find(".header-container .header").once('mtWaypointsFixedHeaderInit').each(function(index, item) {
        var sticky = new Waypoint.Sticky ({
          element: $('.header-container .header')[0],
          stuckClass: 'js-fixed',
          handler: function(direction) {
            if (Waypoint.viewportWidth() > 752) {
              $('body', context).toggleClass('onscroll');
            } else {
              $('body', context).removeClass('onscroll');
            }
            var topValue = $('body').css('padding-top');
            $(".header.js-fixed").css("top", topValue);
          },
          offset: function() {
            var offsetValue = parseInt($('body').css('padding-top')) - 1;
            return offsetValue;
          }
        });
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to add the background color to the .header css class before the .onscroll class is added by javascript. Maybe adding this to your css might do it:

```
.header {
  background-color: rgba(244, 244, 244, 0.95);
}
```

If that's not working, try adding it with !important like so:

```
.header {
  background-color: rgba(244, 244, 244, 0.95) !important;
}
```

Comment: it worked... still going to need a lot of modification to make look right... but I'll work on it...